# How to make an array containing a movieclip to update automaticallly , when moviclip goes null?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying out the following code, so that whenever i make a movieclip null, the array containing it's reference too becomes null.

I understand the following code cannot do this, but i want somehow, the array can provide information, if the movieclip has got null. Any good way to do this ? Any suggestions ?

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

var a_arr:Array = new Array(a_Mc,b_Mc); 

trace(a_arr); 

a_Mc= null ;
trace(a_arr);

//output is:
//[object MovieClip],[object MovieClip]

//  ==>>>> but i want something like null,[object MovieClip ]
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want this behavior? There may be a better way to approach this...

Comment: Besides it's bad to access a null object. It most probably, if a_Mc is null, give you a null pointer exception. So yes: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @cherrun the reference a_Mc is null at that time, but the reference in the array is *not null*, so no NPE.

Answer (score 3):

Its not possible that way, because the variable `a_MC` is only a pointer to the object. You can do this, however:

```
var a_arr:Array = [a_Mc, b_Mc];  // use [] instead of new Array()

a_arr[0] = null;

trace(a_arr);
```

This changes the array pointer value to null.

You can also use custom properties on MovieClip objects since they are dynamic classes (unlike Sprites)

```
 var a_arr:Array = [a_Mc, b_Mc];
 a_Mc.alive = true;
 b_Mc.alive = true;

 // change the custom property
 a_Mc.alive = false;

 // later detect this and solve
 if (a_arr[0].alive){
     trace("ALIVE!");
 }
```

Comment: hmm..thnx for this suggestion but actually i wanted to avoid the use of  dynamic variables. There usage here and there in small quantities, often lead to horrible memory leaks.

Comment: Don't worry about memory leaks since the AS3 VM automatically runs a garbage collector (GC) which finds and deletes unused variables from memory. Just make the app you want.

Answer (score 2):

My knowledge of AS3 is quite rusty, but since the nature of this question is quite general to any programming practice, I'll still try to answer in a language independent way. My solution may not be best if AS3 offers specific mechanism to achieve what you want, but you'll have to listen to other people for that.

From a generic programming point of view the essential problem is that multiple references pointing to a same object don't know about each other. Assigning one of the references to null merely redirects the pointing of this one variable, it doesn't notify other references about the change, and typically doesn't alter the state of the object itself, thus other references still remain pointing to the object. You want the assignment to null to mean "release this object and invalidate all references to it" semantically, but it doesn't happen because of the garbage collection mechanism.

The right way to handle this situation is to use the references the right way -- if you want an object disappear, set all references to it to null. However depending on what you'd like to do in your case (I'm sensing you are trying to do something slightly unorthodox), this may not be possible. You might be able to use the array as the master list and the only place where pointers to the object exist, and always refer to the object by indexing into the array elsewhere.

If you have to do what you said, the most straightforward solution I can think of is to let the object itself carry a flag (has it been marked for release or not) to serve as a way of communication between all the references. Set the flag to true whenever you set a reference to null. Check the flag before dereferencing any reference. I don't know if there's a built-in property in MovieClip that serves a similar purpose, but AS3 is dynamic and you can always add properties yourself. In other languages you can create a wrapper around it to carry the flag. However be warned: this bends one of the fundamental programming concepts (references point to an object don't talk to each other) and if you are not careful, you could get surprises here and there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the index of the item in the collection and set it to null or use splice if you just want to remove it from the collection here's the two options I can think of:

```
        a_arr.splice(a_arr.indexOf(a_Mc),1);
        //or
        a_arr[a_arr.indexOf(a_Mc)] = null;
```